# Null Reference Error Eval(string) passing it to function in code behind

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, gridview, radgrid

I'm trying to get get this RadGrid/Gridview to evaluate what the string value is for this field and to pass it to a function I have in the code behind.

```
 <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Movie Source" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" > 
                <ItemTemplate> 
                          <asp:Image ID="imgStatus2" runat="server" visible="true" ImageURL='<%# Container.DataItem ,GetImageMovie(Eval("MovieSource").ToString()) %>' />
                 </ItemTemplate> 
              </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

unfortunately this is giving me a "null reference error". and I believe I have pinpointed the problem down to the "imageurl" evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

MovieSource is probably null for some records and the null reference error is being thrown when you're trying to convert MovieSource to string.

Instead of calling your GetImageMovie method on the page, it'd be better to set the ImageUrl from the grid's ItemDataBound event. You can then access MovieSource from the ItemDataBound event if you include MovieSource in your DataKeyNames in the MasterTableView of your grid.

That way, you can check if MovieSource is null and do something else in that case i.e. display a generic "image not found" image.